# Limit that appears in particle physics calculation

Tags: limits, analysis, distribution-theory

I came across the following statement, which I do not see how to prove it:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2} =\pi \delta(x)\,.$$
Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: What $\delta (x)$ representing here ?

Comment: @Rishi It's got to be Dirac's $\delta$-function. (Which is not a function, but a distribution, so the mathematically sound proof would need to come from the theory of distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) )

Comment: @hal It would be helpful if you added a bit more context here.  Where is this statement appearing (in particular, what's immediately before it)?  What mathematical background do you have (this can be helpful in terms of where to pitch an explanation; for example, do you know much about the Dirac function)?

Answer (score 3):

As $\delta(x)$ is not a function you cannot do a simple algebraic manipulation.  What you can do is to verify the properties of the delta "function".  You can prove that for $x \neq 0$ your limit is $0$.  You can also prove that $\int\frac{\epsilon\ dx}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\arctan(\frac x\epsilon)+c,$ so the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $\pi$, or the limit of the integral over any interval that crosses $0$ is $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

The area under the function

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)}=1$$

is unit.

Then by scaling,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d\dfrac x\epsilon}{\pi\left(1+\dfrac{x^2}{\epsilon^2}\right)}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\epsilon\,dx}{\pi\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)}.$$

As $\epsilon$ decreases, the peak gets narrower and narrower.